# Entrust Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, users-roles

Llevo varios dias trabajando con Laravel Entrust. Resulta que cuando trato de hacer la validacion de los roles desde las rutas, me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
Class App\Http\Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustRole does not exist
```

Aca mi validacion desde la rutas:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/', 'middleware' => ['role:admin']], function(){
 //Mis rutas
});
```

He realizado todo, tal cual la documentacion original y realmente no se donde me estoy equivocando o realizando un mal paso.

Comment: ¿cómo estás definiendo los middleware en app/Http/Kernel.php?

Comment: 'role' => Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustRole::class,
        'permission' => Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustPermission::class,
        'ability' => Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustAbility::class,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La definición de los middleware para las rutas en `app\Http\Kernel.php` debe ser así según la documentación:

```
'role' => \Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustRole::class,
'permission' => \Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustPermission::class,
'ability' => \Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustAbility::class,
```

Si le quitas el `\` que está al comienzo, estás usando un namespace distinto y la aplicación no los va a encontrar.

Comment: Solucionado gracias a tu sugerencia... Gracias.

Ahora bien, cuando me voy a la vista para mostrar opciones en base a los roles, me da el siguiente error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''admin'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) (View: /home/vagrant/Proyectos/SisPlaniC/resources/views/home.blade.php)

Sabes a que se puede deber ese error.????

Comment: ¿Cuál error? si la respuesta te sirvió, puedes aceptarla, haciendo clic en la marca de "check" que está a la izquierda.

Comment: Este es el codigo que uso en la vista: 

@role('admin')
                        <p class="text-center"><a href="{{ route('communities.index') }}" class="btn btn-action">Acceder...</a></p>
@endrole

Comment: Aquí hay información al respecto: https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust/issues/682

Comment: Listo. Solucionado... Gracias...